# Bootstrapper in caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, bootstrapper

I don't know how I can implement the bootstrapper in my project.

In my App class, I create a new thread which it launches my MainWindow which does not have _ViewModel associate.

I know there is ellaborate boostrapper class which it's proposed but I don't how apply in my wpf project.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this help you:

Add a ResourceDictionary in your App.xaml :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
          <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper"/>                  
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Add a new class "AppBootstrapper" with using Caliburn.Micro:

```
    public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
     {
           public AppBootstrapper()
           {
            this.StartRuntime();
           }

      protected override void OnStartup(object sender,System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
      {
        this.DisplayRootViewFor(typeof(MainViewModel),null);
      }
    }
```

At "this.DisplayRootViewFor(typeof("")" add the name of your viewmodel

Comment: Thanks for your help, I try to integrate this class to my project + the x-key in my app.xaml file but it seems that AppBootstrapper is never called . Does I need to instancy this class from my app.cs file?

Comment: no you dont have to instancy the class in your app.cs. Is there a line StartupUri="" in your App.xaml? if yes, delete them. And did you add the local:-namespace correctly?..so instead of the StartupUri="", there have to be  xmlns:local:="" with your namespace.

Comment: all is ok, I have just an error when I build : "an item with the same key has already been added" on the line "<local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper"/>"...

Comment: maybe i know why...in the AppBootstrapper class, change the line "this.StartRuntime();" to "Initialize();"..then it should work

Comment: Ok so now I changed StartRuntime by Initilalize it builds without errors but my AppBootstrapper is still not called.

Comment: ok, maybe you could post some parts of your code from App.xaml and AppBootstrapper class?

Comment: I change the "Build action" of my App.xaml to "ApplicationDefinition" and it works correctly now. Thanks